# Date search Sql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im storing the timestamp in mysql database in (INT) column, And i want to search the rows with between the dates. Anyone would please help what should be the Sql query to find the rows between two dates?

dates are entered like

```
FROM DATE = 15-10-2011    

END DATE = 01-11-2011
```

Comment: that is not enough information... how are you converting from date to int ? are these Julian dates ?

Comment: so, you are asking how to convert your data into timestamp or what?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what algorithm you use to convert the date strings to `int` values.

If the algoritm is mototonic, for example: If a day (say `15-10-2011`) is converted to `n` (say `5037`), then the next day (`16-10-2011`) is always converted to `n+1` (so `5038` in this example.)

then you could just use:

```
WHERE IntField BETWEEN MySpecialConvertDateToIntFunction('15-10-2011') 
                   AND MySpecialConvertDateToIntFunction('01-11-2011')
```

---

If your field stores different timsetamps as different integers (and the conversion is monotonic), you could change the above code slightly to:

```
WHERE IntField >= MySpecial...Function('15-10-2011') 
  AND IntField < MySpecial...Function('02-11-2011')    --- notice the date+1
```

---

But it's usually better to use a field of the MySQL `DATE` type for storing dates. Unless you want to store dates before `1000` or after `9999` off course.

If you want to store timestamps, there's also a `TIMESTAMP` type. Read the
**[MySQL docs: DATETIME, DATE, and TIMESTAMP Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use The `BETWEEN` operator, which selects a range of data between two values. The values can be numbers, text, or dates.

You can see there:
http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: it is considered bad manner on stackoverflow to link t0 w3schools, as their manuals are buggy and outdated.

Comment: excuse me with it. i will not use it again.

Answer (score -1):

I would ask you to set data type as timestamp/datestamp & then

```
//php code
$date1=date ('Y-m-d' , strtotime ( "15-10-2011") );
$date2=date ('Y-m-d' , strtotime ( "01-11-2011") );
//sql code
SELECT * FROM tbl_mytbl WHERE DATE(attr_date) <'$date2' AND DATE(attr_date) >'$date1'
```

Comment: @Pooja: I'm sure you'd find the error after you had tried this code. `'Y-m-d'` means the Year is first :)

Comment: that's why I asked him to use timestamp/datestamp as data type which'll always b in the format Y-m-d :)

Comment: Oh, you mean PHP's `strtotime()` and `date()` are used to convert the `'15-10-2011'` to the standard format. OK then.

Answer (score -1):

Can you use the mysql FROM_UNIXTIME function [dev.mysql.com - function from_unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
SELECT * 
FROM 'table' 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(intTimestamp) 
BETWEEN 
date ('Y-m-d' , strtotime ( '15-10-2011') ) 
AND ('Y-m-d' , strtotime ( '01-11-2011'));
```

I had made a mistake with the date input but have fixed.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but probably because you used `'15-10-2011'` and not `'2011-10-15'` format. MySQL is not clever enough to indentify both formats, not without telling it which one you use.